# Tag not defined for this message type for MarketDataRequest

Tags: fix-protocol

**Case I:** I'm sending the `MarketDataRequest` (`35=V`) to the FIX server and I am getting `MARKET_DATA_REQUEST_REJECT` answer (`35=Y`) with the text `58=RequestValidationError.ProductNotSet`.

**Case II:** I'm adding to the request a field `Product` with the value `CURRENCY` (`460=4`) and sending it one more time. In result I get a  `REJECT` answer (`35=3`) with the text `58=Tag not defined for this message type` also with `RefTagID` pointing to `Product` (`371=460`). **I'm confused!**

Here is my `C#` code for request:

```
MDReqID mdReqID = new MDReqID("MARKETDATAID");
SubscriptionRequestType subType = new SubscriptionRequestType(SubscriptionRequestType.SNAPSHOT_PLUS_UPDATES);
MarketDepth marketDepth = new MarketDepth(1);

QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup symbolGroup = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup();
symbolGroup.Set(new Symbol("EUR/USD"));

QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest message = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest(mdReqID, subType, marketDepth);
message.MDUpdateType = new MDUpdateType(0);

QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup marketDataEntryGroup = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup();
marketDataEntryGroup.Set(new MDEntryType(MDEntryType.BID));
message.AddGroup(marketDataEntryGroup);
marketDataEntryGroup.Set(new MDEntryType(MDEntryType.OFFER));
message.AddGroup(marketDataEntryGroup);

message.AddGroup(symbolGroup);

message.SetField(new QuickFix.Fields.DeliverToCompID("ALL"));
message.SetField(new QuickFix.Fields.Product(QuickFix.Fields.Product.CURRENCY));
```

Here are the request and respond related to Case I:

```
ToApp 8=FIX.4.4 9=165 35=V 34=2 49=XXXX 50=YYYY 52=20141227-10:11:27.728 56=demo.fxgrid 128=ALL 262=MARKETDATAID 263=1 264=1 265=0 267=2 269=0 269=1 146=1 55=EUR/USD 10=104 
FromApp 8=FIX.4.4 9=138 35=Y 34=2 49=demo.fxgrid 52=20141227-10:11:28.716 56=XXXX 58=RequestValidationError.ProductNotSet 262=MARKETDATAID 281=3 10=218
```

Here are the request and respond related to Case II:

```
ToApp 8=FIX.4.4  9=171  35=V  34=2  49=XXXX  50=YYYY  52=20141227-10:19:59.744  56=demo.fxgrid  128=ALL  262=MARKETDATAID  263=1  264=1  265=0  460=4  267=2  269=0  269=1  146=1  55=EUR/USD  10=124  
FromAdmin 8=FIX.4.4  9=161  35=3  34=2  49=demo.fxgrid  52=20141227-10:20:00.741  56=XXXX  57=YYYY  115=ALL  45=2  58=Tag not defined for this message type  371=460  372=V  373=2  10=221
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case 1:** This is not a FIX or QuickFIX error.  Your message was valid per FIX protocol, but it's not what your counterparty expects.

That error message in tag 58 was set by your counterparty.  It sounds like you haven't read your counterparty's documentation that tells you what fields they expect you to set.

**Case 2:** Tag 460 doesn't belong to the top level of the `MarketDataRequest` message per the default FIX message definitions.  Thus, it's an illegal message.  (It sounds like you are new to FIX, because this is kind of a newbie mistake.)

**Note:** Your counterparty is probably using a modified version of the default definitions, so you'll also need to modify your FIX44.xml DataDictionary file to match their definitions.  Again, this will be in their docs.

**BOTTOM LINE: Read your counterparty's docs before you do any more development!**

Answer (score 0):

Mr. don't hurry. In QuickFix definitely an error in the receiving code. I found it by checking  a tag by tag. in RefTagID < 371 > field, the tag number is incorrect. Solution is checking all fields in FIX.xml