# FIX Message: "Tag not defined for this message type" upon Logon

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

Below is the output snippet I get while I try to logon to Cfh [I am following this doument](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fzb.oschina.net%2Ffile%2Fget%3Fpath%3Dgroup1%2FM00%2F0C%2F94%2FwKgBDVwgtXeAO4LsABE8J9JtyHE286.pdf%26name%3DCFH%2520Clearing%2520FIX%2520API%2520v.%25202.5%2520(1).pdf&psig=AOvVaw2NDP7ot6_JVzfgX2Wz59E5&ust=1582245001635000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCKiytozw3ucCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=119|35=0|34=2|49=xxxxxxx|52=20200220-00:14:00.478|56=CfhDemoxxxxx|108=30|141=Y|553=xxxxxxx|554=xxxxxx|10=227|
8=FIX.4.4|9=138|35=3|34=2|49=CfhDemoxxxxx|52=20200220-00:14:00.564|56=xxxxxxx|45=2|58=Tag not defined for this message type|371=108|372=0|373=2|10=154|
8=FIX.4.4|9=113|35=1|34=3|49=CfhDemoxxxxx|52=20200220-00:14:06.564|56=xxxxxxxx|112=2439c450-1914-42ad-83c6-ad4b5ed17501|10=146|
8=FIX.4.4|9=160|35=0|34=3|49=xxxxxxx|52=20200220-00:14:06.740|56=CfhDemoxxxx|108=30|112=2439c450-1914-42ad-83c6-ad4b5ed17501|141=Y|553=xxxxxxxx|554=xxxxxxx|10=135|
8=FIX.4.4|9=138|35=3|34=4|49=CfhDemoxxxx|52=20200220-00:14:06.826|56=xxxxxxx|45=3|58=Tag not defined for this message type|371=108|372=0|373=2|10=164|
8=FIX.4.4|9=119|35=5|34=4|49=xxxxxxx|52=20200220-00:14:23.476|56=CfhDemoxxxxx|108=30|141=Y|553=xxxxxxx|554=xxxxxxB|10=237|
8=FIX.4.4|9=138|35=3|34=5|49=CfhDemoxxxxx|52=20200220-00:14:23.563|56=xxxxxxx|45=4|58=Tag not defined for this message type|371=108|372=5|373=2|10=168|
```

Comment: It is basically the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666608/tag-not-defined-for-this-message-type-for-marketdatarequest?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to see it (so you can ignore my comment) but that was mainly due to bad formatting. Please paste your FIX messages with a visible separator between the fields, e.g. a pipe `|`

You are sending a `Heartbeat` message (`35=0`) with field `108/HeartBtInt`. This tag is only allowed on a `Logon` message (`35=A`).

This is also explained in the `Reject` message (`35=3`) that you get:

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=138|35=3|34=2|49=CfhDemoxxxxx|52=20200220-00:14:00.564|56=xxxxxxx|45=2|58=Tag not defined for this message type|371=108|372=0|373=2|10=154|

...
58      Text        Tag not defined for this message type   
371     RefTagID    108     
372     RefMsgType  0
...
```

So `371/RefTagID` tells you that tag `108` is not defined for the `372/RefMsgType` of `0`.

Edit: in general it seems you are putting wrong tags on every message. You also put tags `141`, `553` and `554` on a `HeartBeat` but these belong to a `Logon` message also.

Comment: Sounds like someone is using `toAdmin` to add fields without wrapping it in `if(msgType==login)`.  Hey @BalaB, see the first question in [this FAQ](https://quickfixj.org/wiki/display/qfj/User+FAQ).

Comment: Yes I am sending this to logon.

Comment: According to your message log you don't. You are putting this to Heartbeat messages.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Now I removed heartbeat. After executing, Now I get.

Comment: I am using Quickfixj
 toAdmin: Message=8=FIX.4.49=7235=034=249=ParagSinghal_FIX52=20200220-15:22:02.88356=CfhDemoPrices10=192, SessionId=FIX.4.4:ParagSinghal_FIX->CfhDemoPrices
 fromAdmin: Message=8=FIX.4.49=13835=334=349=CfhDemoPrices52=20200220-15:22:02.96856=ParagSinghal_FIX45=258=Tag not defined for this message type371=553372=0373=210=174, SessionId=FIX.4.4:ParagSinghal_FIX->CfhDemoPrices
 receivedType:3

Comment: Now it seems you sent tag 553 on Heartbeat message. I already mentioned that in my answer. Could it be that your check for the message type is wrong? You need to do `getHeader()` on the message to retrieve the `MsgType` field. Otherwise please edit your question to contain your `toAdmin()` method.